# Azure B2C Identity Experience Framework for MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How to enable Phone number verification in custom policy or MFA ? Default policy allows so , is it possible to do so in custom policy?

My requirement is to use e Phone Number as user id in Azure b2c? Is it possible to have user id accepting both phone # or email id?

Similar to Facebook accepting either phone # or email id. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A starter pack with MFA can be found at:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa

Phone number based sign up and sign in could be possible but it will require you to determine your user journeys in detail. You will need to create a separate experience for phone number sign up and email sign up because their verification and storage in Azure AD is different.

Similarly, when a user needs to sign in, the country code for their phone number needs to be determined. Currently, there is no easy way to do this on the sign in page.

In short, I do not think there is an easy way to support Facebook like support for phone no and email address simultaneously. However, it is an area that Azure AD B2C team wants to invest in so we may see support in the future.